# Different Php Zend opcache settings by path

Tags: php, symfony, optimization, zend-framework, opcache

I would like to optimize opcache when developing a Php Symfony 3 project.

Nowadays, most of Php projects are using composer. So there are 2 different folders containing Php files:

- vendor => contains files that never change
- src => contains business related code sources, change a lot in developmenent

Hence my question, is it possible to configure opcache so that "vendor" Php files cache is very aggressive whereas src Php files cache not?